# string to list in special format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string containing comma separated names and optional values that seprated values like this:

```
var str = "PowerOn:On,ValidLocation, temp:25";
```

I want to convert it into objects or json that can access to values by name like this:

```
var a = {"PowerOn":"On", "ValidLocation":"true", "temp":25};
var result = a.PowerOn;
alert(result);
```

OR

```
var a = {"PowerOn":"On", "ValidLocation":"true", "temp":25};
var result = a["PowerOn"];
alert(result);
```

> Note 1: If a name doesn't have value it be true by default.

**Update:**

> Note 2 :If a name doesn't exist in list  the value of it be false: ex:

```
var a = {"PowerOn":"On", "ValidLocation":"true", "temp":25};
var result = a.Alarm 
//result must be false
```

Comment: What Can I DO? I recieve a string from a database and i must parse it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var str = "PowerOn:On,ValidLocation, temp:25",
    arr = str.split(','),
    obj = {}

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var parts = arr[i].split(':');
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1] || true;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TxMhM/)

Comment: so thanx :) another problem: if a name doesn't exist in list i want the value of it be false: ex: var result = a.Alarm

Comment: @ArMaN it won't be false. It'll be undefined, but that's falsy anyways, so if you do `if(!obj.NonExistingKey){alert('doesn\'t exist');}` you'll get an alert...

Comment: Just do `var result = a.Alarm || false`, or `var result = Alarm in a ? a.Alarm : false;` etc

Comment: @adeneo Also, this will cause problems if you have an empty string, or space in front of the keys (as shown on the `temp` one). See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TxMhM/1/ can't guarantee this is what OP wants though.

Comment: @Alxandr - Yeah, there are still a lot of things that could go wrong, so trimming and optimizing to make sure the values are valid is always a good idea if the OP isn't sure the original string is exactly like in the question.

Comment: @adeneo We're working with javascript. Is there any cases where thing's **can't** go wrong? I mean `(function(undefined) { console.log(undefined); }(true));` xD

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the delimiters remain as such, Does this work for you :

```
var result = {}; 

"PowerOn:On,ValidLocation, temp:25".split(",").forEach(function(i) { 
           result[(i=i.split(":"))[0]]=i[1] || true; 
});

// result : {PowerOn: "On", ValidLocation: true,  temp: "25"}
```

---

To the second part of you question use `!!result.Alarm` which should be `false`.